# Error on attempting to import data from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ssis

I am trying to import data from an Access 2003 mdb database using OpenDataSource with the ACE OLEDB driver. I'm getting this error:

```
 Description: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.".
```

I have no idea what it's talking about, and my internet searches have not helped. They all refer to linked servers, and anything I've tried has done nothing to fix the problem. What does this error mean, and what do I need to do to fix it?

The sproc which does the importing is called from an SSIS package, which goes through a table of file locations and calls the sproc for each of them. I just discovered that the package ran for about half an hour, getting about 80 files imported, before it began throwing this error. I have as yet been unable to find any difference between the files that worked and the ones that didn't.

Comment: How do you open your Access file from your desktop? Do you use a shortcut?

Comment: I don't. These Access files are never opened, they're just data storage from a third party application. I tried opening one earlier, though, and it opened fine

Comment: What are your permissions like? Have you tried windows authentication?

Comment: Well, here's what the line looks like that imports the data: `SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO tbl_Mail_Pieces (TrayNbr, Barcode, PalletNbr) (SELECT TrayNo,PieceBC,PalletNo FROM OpenDataSource( ' + '''' + 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'Data Source="' + @Path+ '";User ID=****;Password=****;SystemDB=C:\mydatabase.mdw;'+'''' + ')...IMBPieceBC)'
`

Comment: If the file opens without asking for any password on your desktop, then it seems unlikely that you have User Level security set up in MS Access. It seems more likely that the error is misleading and something to do with the SQL Server temp folder. For example, can you import from any Access file? I am no expert, but I had trouble with permissions and ACE.

Comment: I can execute a select query on one of the same mdb files if I do it from SSMS on server itself, logged in as a windows account instead of a SQL account, but the trying to execute the job that calls the SSIS package still fails.

Comment: Anything to do with "BTW, some of you are probably already thinking “Why didn’t he just use SQL Server’s Import and Export Wizard?”. Well, the wizard uses SSIS and SSIS is a 32bit application which means that the 64bit Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider (a.k.a. Microsoft ACE OLE DB 12.0 Provider) is not available in the wizard" -- http://blog.wharton.com.au/2012/02/16/openrowset-t-sql-sometimes-you-have-to-stop-and-smell-the-roses/

Comment: That is, a 32/64 bit problem?

Comment: Well, the server itself is 32 bit. I think the import/export wizard works, but the problem is I need this to be programmatic, so that I can have it done automatically each night.

Comment: Would it be fair to say at this stage that what you have is more an SSIS problem rather than an MS Access problem, given that most of the parts work? Perhaps an SSIS tag might attract some more ideas?

Comment: You may be right, I'll add that in. Everywhere I've read says that this is some sort of permissions issue, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: This was a step for me, I offer it with no real expectations "Provide full access to the "\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Local Settings\Temp" for any account that needs to run the queries."

Comment: Hm, the NetworkService folder doesn't exist on the SQL Server, and I can't find it on the network storage server.

Answer (score 2):

From [Understanding the role of workgroup information files in Access security](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305542):

> The workgroup information file is a required component when you use a
>   Microsoft Access database (MDB). This file is required for both a
>   run-time installation and a full installation of Microsoft Access.
>   This file is an important component of Microsoft Access security.
>
> If you develop database applications, it is important that you have a
>   good understanding of the workgroup information file. It is a good
>   idea to reserve the last phase of the development process for applying
>   security in Access. Until then, you can develop the database
>   application in an unsecured database.
>
> A workgroup is a group of users who share data in a multiuser
>   environment. When security is implemented on a database, the user and
>   group accounts are recorded in the workgroup information file. User
>   passwords are also stored in the workgroup information file.
>
> IMPORTANT: If you establish Access security in a database, Microsoft
>   recommends that you store a backup copy of the workgroup information
>   file in a safe location. **If the file is lost or damaged, the only way
>   to recover the workgroup information file quickly is to restore the
>   file from a backup copy. If you do not have a backup copy, you must
>   re-create the User and Group Accounts with the same Personal IDs that
>   were originally assigned. If the new workgroup information file is not
>   created exactly as the original file, you will not be able to open the
>   database with the workgroup file.**
>
> Access uses the workgroup information file even when the database has
>   not been secured. The default Admin user account, which is stored in
>   the workgroup information file, is used to open all unsecured
>   databases. If you assign a password to the Admin user, you will
>   receive a logon prompt when you reopen the database.

Comment: Good information, but what do I need to do to take care of the SQL error?

Comment: @SaintWacko Make sure the .mdw file exists. If it does not, follow the steps abvoe to recreate.

Comment: Where can I find this .mdw file?

Comment: From the article I linked to: *By default, on computers that are running Microsoft Windows 2000, the System.mdw file is created in the user profile in the following path. 

NOTE: The Application Data folder is a hidden folder.
C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application Data\Microsoft\Access\System.MDW
On computers that are running Microsoft Windows 98, the default System.MDW file is created in the following path:
C:\Windows\Application Data\Microsoft\Access\System.MDW*

Comment: It's there on the SQL server machine, however, the files I'm trying to access are on a network server. Does that change anything?

Comment: You can specify the workgeroup file location in your conenction string, e.g.: *Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.accdb;SystemDB=C:\mydatabase.mdw;*

Comment: Try moving the workgroup file to the same network folder as the database and reference it from there in your connection string.

Comment: Well that's odd... This stored procedure is called from a SSIS package which goes through a table containing file paths, and for each path runs this sproc which imports data. I just discovered, while figuring out a way to follow your suggestion, that the package ran partially through the list, for about half an hour, and only then began failing with this error. And the ones that succeeded did not have a local system.mdw either.

Answer (score 1):

The Access database that SQL Server is trying to access is being used by another user.  Go to the folder where the database is stored.  With Access 2003, the database file itself will end in 'mdb'.  If there is a file with the same name but ending in 'idb', it signals that there is a user currently using the 'mdb' file.  Have the user exit the database and then run your package.  If you can't find the user using the file, make a copy of the file in another folder and edit your SSIS package to reflect the change.

Comment: Are all of the records in your file location table of tables that actually exist?  Also, are all of the DBs in the folder in .mdb format?  Access 2007 and 2010 DBs are saved as .accdb by default

Comment: Yes, they all exist. And they are all .mdb. The third party program saves them in that format.